# Swapping words in Java

Tags: java

I am a newcomer to Java and want to swap two words that are entered into the program and then saved as a string. I included an if statement to make sure the two words I want to switch are entered.

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter at least one thing you love and one thing you hate using the words hate and love: ");
  String loveHate = in.nextLine();



  if (loveHate.indexOf( "love" ) == -1 || loveHate.indexOf( "hate" ) == -1 ){
    System.out.println("Please include the words love and hate.");
    return; 
  }
```

I want to take the sentence the user inputs and switch the words love and hate and then reprint a new string with the words switched.

Comment: Great to know, but what have you tried, and what is your question?

Comment: I've tried loveHate.replaceAll("hate","love") and that works but it only switches and replaces one word, not replacing both words with their opposites. I need something that takes a user input (lets say "I hate cats and love dogs") and switches the words love and hate so it prints out "I love cats and hate dogs."

Comment: Yes, you need a temporary string so you don't lose one half - see my answer below.

Comment: @DNA One more thing. If you want only the stand-alone words **love** and **hate** to be changed, then the current solution is not correct. With `replaceAll`, a word like **clove** will be changed to **chate**. If you don't want this to happen, you'll have to split the string into individual words, check for exact whole-word matches, make the changes and combine again into a sentence.

Answer (score 3):

A crude way, provided you don't expect the text "xxxx" in your input is a standard swap:

```
...
String loveHate = in.nextLine();

String hateLove = loveHate.replaceAll("love", "xxxx");
       hateLove = hateLove.replaceAll("hate", "love");
       hateLove = hateLove.replaceAll("xxxx", "hate");

System.out.println("Changed "+loveHate+" into "+hateLove);
```

Comment: +1 Good solution. Use `replaceAll()` instead. Else you'll have to do this many times.

Comment: Oops, yes, quite right. Will edit the answer.

Comment: that worked perfectly! But how would I reprint the original line as well? can change loveHate = loveHate.replaceAll("love", "xxxx") into loveHate1 = loveHate.replaceAll("love", "xxxx"); and then print both the original and reformated versions?

Comment: @user1701604 Save a copy of the original.

Comment: awesome thats the same thing I went back and did in the program and it worked perfectly. I appreciate your help it made my night a lot less stressful.

Comment: Instead of "xxxx" as the temp replacement, use something that a user wouldn't enter, such as the null character \0.